# cordova inappbrowser fit image on screen (ios)

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

is there any possibility to fit image on screen in cordova inapprowser?

If I use ref.executeScript to set image width 100% of screen it's fitted but size of the page still larger than screen and i can scroll it left

```
var ref = window.open(path, param, "location=no,suppressesIncrementalRendering=yes,enableViewportScale=yes");
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
     ref.executeScript({ 
                 code: "var imageResize = document.querySelectorAll('img'); var screenWidth = window.innerWidth; for (var i = 0; i < imageResize.length; i++) {imageResize[i].style.width = screenWidth + 'px';}"  });
      });
```

Comment: Hi, did you get an answer to this?